# Is $\frac{\mathbb{F}_p(u)[X]}{(X^n-u)}$ a normal field extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(u)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{F}_p(u) $ and $L = \frac{K[X]}{(X^n-u)}$ . For which $n$ is $L/K$ a normal field extension?

This is what I could come up with:

For every $n$ we have that $x^n-u \in K[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial over $K$ because of the generalised eisenstein criterion with prime ideal $(u)$. Therefore, if $L/K$ is a normal field extension $x^n-u$ splits in linear factors over $L$. Conversely, if $x^n-u$ splits over $L$ then $L$ is the splitting field of $x^n-u$, so $L/K$ would be normal.

So i think that this question boils down to finding out the $n$ such that $x^n-u$ splits over $L$. In any case we have $x^n-u = (x-X)(x^{n-1}+Xx^{n-2}+X^2x^{n-3}+\cdots+X^{n-2}x+X^{n-1})$. When/how would this split further?

Also, i think that if $L$ would contain $n$ $n$-th roots of unity, say $1=\omega_1,\omega_2,\cdots,\omega_n$, then $x^n-u$ would split into $(x-X)(x-\omega_1X)\cdots(x-\omega_nX)$. Conversely, if all $n$ roots of $x^n-u$ are contained in $L$, then dividing all these roots by $X$ gives $n$ $n$-th roots of unity. So $L/K$ is normal if and only if $L$ contains all $n$ $n$-th roots of unity.

Comment: If $\omega$ is a root of unity in $K(u)$, can you show that $\omega\in K$?

Comment: I can, how would that help here?

Comment: In your case, for what $n$ does $\mathbb{F}_p$ have an $n$-th root of unity?

Comment: That would be if $n$ divides $p-1$. So $K$ does only have $n$-th roots of unity if $n$ divides $p-1$. But shouldn't we be looking for roots of unity in $L$? Are you hinting that any root of unity in $L$ also in $K$?

Comment: $L=\mathbb{F}_p(v)$, where $v$ is an $n$-th root of $u$.

Comment: I get it, thanks a lot!